# How to know whether "over" means more than or during?

Tags: word-meaning

**Over** has two meaning;

> : more than (a specified number or amount)
>   : throughout or during (a particular amount of time)

We can distinguish it in context but sometimes it's ambiguous for me.

For example

> I lived there over 5 years.
>   It's been over a minute.

This kind of sentence is confusing for me. Above all, is it *preposition* or *adverb*?

If it's preposition, I copied two examples more from Merriam-Webster.

> I've been waiting for over an hour.
>   happening/occurring/developing over a period of 20 years.

According to the dictionary, it means *more than* in first sentence but it means *during* in second sentence. How to know whether **over** means *more than* or *during*?

Plus, what if second sentence was *happening/occurring/developing over 20 years.*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ambiguity between "over" meaning "more than" and "over" meaning "during" can only arise where an adverbial of time is expected.

In a sentence like:

- It's been **over** a minute (since he left).

we expect a noun or adjective phrase or an adverb of place after "be":

- It's been **a mess** these days.
- It's been **noisy** lately.
- It's been **there** for a while.

Notice that adverbials of time can only come after the words or phrases in bold above. That means that "over a minute" in your sentence cannot be an adverbial of time, meaning "during a minute," but a noun phrase meaning "more than a minute."

In:

> I lived there **over** five years.

although we expect an adverbial of time after "I lived there," I don't think "over" usually collocates with the verb "live" to mean "during." In this case, we'd use "for" (or no preposition):

> I lived there **for** five years.

With other verbs, like "extend," we may need to use both prepositions to indicate duration + "more than":

- The war extended **over** thirty years (= during thirty years)
- The war extended **for** thirty years (= during thirty years)
- The war extended **for over** thirty years (= during more than thirty years)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid that I don't have the sense of expectation of adverbials of time. For example, I don't even understand the sentence(what follows the verb "be" cannot be an adverbial of time). Sometimes we expect an adverbial of time after *be*. Like, It's been a while since we met.

Comment: @TingChoe "a while" is a noun phrase there, similar to "a long time." By adverbials of time I mean phrases that can specify the time of occurrence of the state or action described by the verb, like "We met **long ago**" or "We stayed there **for a while**."

Comment: @TingChoe I'll see if I can improve my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Hu.... I almost got your point. I'm still confused, though. I will read your answer whenever I'm confused between them. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @TingChoe I've seen you posted the same question at ELU site. Maybe you'll get some more answers there, though I honestly don't think much more can be said about the issue.

Comment: Yepp. I just wanted listen to the other's opinion. People explain differently. I will refer yours and theirs to help my understand more clear. Btw, is the question proper for ELU?

Comment: @TingChoe It's not 100% clear to me when questions are suitable for ELU and when they are not. There seems to be some overlapping with ELL.

Comment: @JasonC That was only to show that after "be" we will tend to find adverbials other than temporal ("there" is locative). Time adverbials will only appear afterwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55259/discussion-between-ting-choe-and-gustavson).